# Narrowing down injection moulding material selection

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method, manufacturing-engineering, plastic

How do I narrow down specific values when selecting a plastic for injection moulding?

My part is uniform in wall thickness and thins out where a hinge a present.

Properties:

- Will not go under many cycles in its lifetime, however, needs to be rated for thousands of cycles
- The entire part is about as long as a finger and the hinge will displace minor distances (2-3 mm)
- Will have to operate in temperatures from -20 to 60 Celsius
- Applied forces are minor and not sudden

I have designed the hinge as follows:

[image: Right Angle Hinge]

I have the model in CAD and have run FEA to figure out stresses (ie. Von Mises). I have also 3D printed it in ABS, and it has passed vibration testing and performs as designed.

The criteria I have narrowed down based on matweb is:

1. I need the hinge to bend easily, so it does not affect the entire product- **a low flexural modulus**
2. As the plastic part is supported in one area, I need it to be able to withstand vibration testing. Therefore, sorting by the **lowest density** so that it does not collapse underneath its own weight
3. **Shore Hardness D** of around 60 to 80, as I need the part to not be flimsy yet not too rigid
4. Despite the hinge being able to bent easily, I need it to also return to its original form when it is not stressed- *a high resilience*

How do I go about determining specific values for the criteria? Are there other mechanical values I am neglecting?

Comment: One approach would be to look at what materials are available from your vendor and work backwards from there. Also, point 4 I think you could interchange resilience with yield stress.